# Problem while building a binary package in R

Tags: r, build, package

I am new in R and I am trying to learn how to build a binary package.
Actually, I tried to build a source package and it worked but I have a problem with the binary one.
I attach the error.

```
installing to C:/Users/Martino/Documents/R/win-library/4.0/00LOCK-ciao/00new/ciao/libs/x64
** R
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
Errore: unexpected string constant in:
"suppressPackageStartupMessages(.getRequiredPackages(quietly = TRUE))
tools:::makeLazyLoading("ciao", '"
Esecuzione interrotta
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'ciao'
* removing 'C:/Users/Martino/Documents/R/win-library/4.0/ciao'

Exited with status 1.`
```

After a research, it seems that I have to delete the "00LOCK-ciao" file but I do not find it, as if it was not present in the directory.
The code that triggered the error is the following:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
List rcpp_hello() {
CharacterVector x = CharacterVector::create("foo", "bar");
NumericVector y   = NumericVector::create(0.0, 1.0);
List z            = List::create(x, y);
return z;
}
```

It is a simple code, because it is a test.
To build the package I simply used the "build" button on the top of R studio interface and then I used build binary package.
Did someone find the same error in the past? Can you help me to find a solution, please?

Comment: Post the code that was used prior to the error message. If you only post the error message the causes remain a puzzle.

Comment: You should show us what you did to trigger that message.  How were you trying to do the build?  One thing I can say:  the "00LOCK-ciao" message is entirely internal to R package installation.  When it tries to install a new version of an existing package, it renames the old one to that name, and deletes it at the end if the new install is successful.

Comment: ... or maybe it's the other way around, and it installs the new one into "00LOCK-ciao".  I forget.

Comment: Thank you guys, I edited the question so you can find the code and how I built the package

Comment: That's not a package.  If that's the only file you have, that would cause an error.